# Why does bash still keep duplicate lines with erasedups?

Tags: bash, command-history

I have the following line in my ~/.bashrc

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

However whenever I run `somecommand` it keeps adding the duplicated command into `.bash_history` like this

```
grep -w somecommand ~/.bash_history
somecommand
somecommand abc xyz
somecommand 123
somecommand
...
```

Why is this and how to prevent it?

Comment: [How to avoid duplicate entries in .bash_history](https://askubuntu.com/q/15926/253474)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

> A value of ignoredups  causes  lines matching the previous history entry
>   to not be saved.

If you run `somecommand` twice in a row with no arguments, you should see only one *consecutive* entry.

Likewise if you run `somecommand 123` twice in a row, it will only be added to the history once.

The commands in your list show no *consecutive* duplicates, so this feature is working as intended.

Comment: ah, I thought that it will remove the previous duplicate entry. So it seems less useful than expected, because sometimes I run `cmdA` then `cmdB` then `cmdA` it still shows 2 `cmdA`s nearby

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I'm curious: are you trying to get a clean readable history list, or are you trying to easily re-execute commands you've run earlier?  (If the latter, [you might try using `fc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399987/135943).

Comment: I constantly use Ctrl+R to find commands I've used and it shows many duplicates which is a bit annoying

Comment: I believe that the question is about `erasedups` not `ignoredups` (please read the title). In any case, your answer does not explain such option

Answer (score 8):

The `erasedups` option will remove duplicated lines limited by this two conditions:

- The lines will be erased from the list in **memory**.
- Only when a new command is going to be added to the list.

The list in memory is the output of `history`.
The whole list "in memory" will be written to file with `history -w` or when bash is closed (if histappend is not set).

So, if the list in memory is:

```
$ history
1  cmd1
2  cmd2
3  cmd3
4  cmd1
5  cmd2
6  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
7  history
```

It will become:

```
$ history
1  cmd2
2  cmd3
3  cmd2
4  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
5  cmd1
6  history
```

All cmd1 commands (except the one being appended) are removed.

If `cmd2` is executed, all repeats of `cmd2` are also removed (also `history`):

```
$ cmd2
$ history
1  cmd3
2  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
3  cmd1
4  cmd2
5  history
```

But even now, the file `~/.bash_history` has not been modified. It still contains the list of commands from a previous session. Using grep on the file may show many duplicates (dups), including the commands just used (cmd1 and cmd2). A grep will only work correctly on the memory list:

```
$ history | grep cmd1
```

Once the list gets written to file (history -w) is it correct that only one instance of each command line used in the session.will be found with grep.

You can force an update of the disk file every time with:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Answer (score 1):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```

Comment: There is no need to add anything to `~/.bash_logout`. By default bash store the memory list to file on exit.